# How do I convert font style to font weight in Java?

Tags: java, javafx, fonts, styles

I want to set a specific ont to a `Text` within a `TextFlow` in JavaFx.

However, `Font` has only `static .font()` methods, which expects a `FontWeight` instance.

How do I convert a font style like "Regular" to a `FontWeight` instance? There is no "Regular" in the final fields of Font.

Comment: There are actually no final fields in `Font` at all. Everything is represented by enums.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that "Enum.somethings" aren't called fields! Thanks.

Comment: They are called fields, but they are not fields of `Font`. (They are fields of `FontWeight` and `FontPosture`, respectively.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "Regular" style, just use one of the static methods taking a font name and/or size:

```
text.setFont(Font.font(12)); // 12 point, default font family
```

or

```
text.setFont(Font.font("Serif")); // default font size
```

or

```
text.setFont(Font.font("Serif", 12)); // 12 point serif...
```

The [`FontWeight` enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/FontWeight.html) specifies the "weight" of the font (i.e. bold, extra bold, light, etc); its default value is [`FontWeight.NORMAL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/FontWeight.html#NORMAL).

The [`FontPosture` enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/FontPosture.html) specifies whether or not the font is italic; it's values are [`FontPosture.REGULAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/FontPosture.html#REGULAR) and [`FontPosture.ITALIC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/FontPosture.html#ITALIC).

The `Font.font(...)` methods are overloaded to take most combinations of font name, size, weight, and posture, reverting to default values if they are not supplied. So

```
text.setFont(Font.font("Serif", 12));
```

is equivalent to

```
text.setFont(Font.font("Serif", FontWeight.NORMAL, FontPosture.REGULAR, 12));
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! So FontWeight + FontPosture are not some old remains from before FontStyle, but are actually a distiction of terms, it seems.